# Why did Yonatan start up with the Plishtim?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, army-military-war, samuel-shmuel-book-of

In 1 Shmuel 13 Yonatan seemingly unprovoked, attacks the Plishtim triggering a war. The text does not indicate that Yonatan was told to do this by Shaul, Shmuel or Hashem. Further on in the chapter we learn that none of the Jewish army had any weapons other than Shaul and Yonatan. The end result was a Jewish victory but that was far from clearly an inevitable outcome when Yonatan acted. I have not found any commentaries which explain Yonatan's motives (Radak says he wanted to start a war, but doesn't explain why, with what authority, or why he would think the Jews would win).

Please explain why Yonatan attacked the Plishtim and cite sources to support your explanation.

Comment: The Plishtim for many years had been slowly conquering more and more Israelite land. In the time of Shimshon they terrorized Yehudah. This particular battle involved jumping a Plishtite garrison in Michmash, way out in the middle of the territory of Binyamin (!), which shows how far they had advanced inland. Shmuel 1:13:20-21 shows that the Plishtim did not allow the Israelites iron weapons and controlled their entire iron market. In short, the Plishtim controlled Israel with an iron fist and Yonatan saw an opportunity to free Yisrael from them.